# MySql SELECT COUNT ... NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sql-like

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN restricted LIKE '%us%' THEN 2 
                ELSE 1 
            END) AS totalcount 
FROM 
    reviews 
WHERE 
    restricted LIKE '%us%'
```

This counts the total number of values like "us" appearing in a column (restricted). This column is filled by values from a muultiselect checkbox in this "unusual" manner:

*us*ca*uk* etc.

And this works. No problem.

Now, I need to count where this value (us) is NOT appearing.
I tried to do this, a "classic".

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN restricted NOT LIKE '%us%' THEN 2 
                ELSE 1 
            END
    ) AS totalcount 
FROM 
    reviews 
WHERE 
    restricted NOT LIKE '%us%'
```

I have declared the statemenent NOT LIKE but now... the problem... it count also rows where 'restricted' column is NOT FILLED (some listings don't use this column). And the count is wrong.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: There is no need for the CASE statement.  Your WHERE clause means the ELSE will NEVER be hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

empty value or null value on 'restricted' column will pass "restricted NOT LIKE '%us%'
" statement. try change to:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
            CASE 
                WHEN restricted NOT LIKE '%us%' THEN 2 
                ELSE 1 
            END
    ) AS totalcount 
FROM 
    reviews 
WHERE 
    restricted NOT LIKE '%us%' 
    AND restricted != '' 
    AND restricted IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: So why have a CASE statement?  It is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
FROM 
    reviews 
WHERE 
    restricted IS NOT NULL 
-- In case you expect restricted to contain spaces, the following line should be 
-- LTRIM(RTRIM(restricted)) != ''
AND restricted != '' 
AND restricted NOT LIKE '%us%'
```

This would filter out the rows where restricted is either null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the CASE statement. Your WHERE clause means the ELSE will NEVER be hit.

Matching "us":

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(restricted) AS 'Count matching *us*' 
FROM 
  reviews 
WHERE 
  restricted IS NOT NULL 
  AND restricted LIKE '%us%'
```

Not matching "us" (includes null):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(restricted) AS 'Count not matching *us*' 
FROM 
  reviews 
WHERE 
  restricted IS NULL 
  OR restricted NOT LIKE '%us%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
FROM 
    reviews 
WHERE 
    restricted IS NOT NULL
```

In case you expect restricted to contain spaces, the following line should be

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(restricted)) != ''
AND restricted != '' 
AND restricted NOT LIKE '%us%'
```